# Is it possible to check if a slide in one PowerPoint presentation is the same as a slide in another deck?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, checksum

I need to be able to determine whether (some) slides in two presentations are identical. Essentially a master presentation is updated every month and the previous version archived. The slide order remains the same, just the content of those slides *may* have changed. The trouble is...

```
deck1.Slides(i)=deck2.Slides(i)
```

...doesn't work, and ...

```
deck1.Slides(i).SlideID=deck2.Slides(i).SlideID
```

...returns identical values even if the slide content has changed.

I was wondering whether it is possible to checksum slides, but I haven't found anything online that would accomplish this -- the VBA checksum routines I've come across including on here are for text strings only. Is it possible to checksum slides or objects, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but from what little experience I have with PowerPoint-automation, I would expect you have to Loop over the contents of the slides you want to compare (i guess the objects inside the .shapes-collection would be the relevant ones)

Comment: Define "identical". Are they the same if a) the text is the same, but the text colour has changed, b) the text boxes have been moved, c) an image has been added or resized... etc? You will have to write code to check all the parameters one by one. PowerPoint is **not** designed for this. It is a presentation tool, not a reporting program. If you use it for reporting, the joke's on you...

Comment: Welcome to the financial services industry which uses PowerPoint for this sort of thing! By identical, I mean exactly the same, so text colour changes, shape movements would all be caught by this – if it is possible…

Comment: Not a solution but PowerPoint supportd Merge and MergeWithBaseline which can be used while comparing two decks. This would then populate the UI with the changes between the presentations in Review pane.

Comment: Another possible approach:  export both slides to PNG files and compare checksums on the PNGs.

Comment: Shyam: there might be some mileage in that approach, but would it know if a linked slide or object had been updated?

Comment: Steve: Is that possible to do wholly within PowerPoint (say stored within a byte array); or would the PNG images have to be saved first – and can the FileSystemObject (or something similar) generate checksums?

Answer (score 0):

While this is by no means a ready-to-deploy solution, this might provide a starting point, provided your specific task is to check for changed text-contents in seemingly identical presentations.

I narrowed this down to comparing the text-contents of Textboxes (shape-type 14) on Slide 1 for this demonstration.

```
Sub Neu()
    Dim ppt As New PowerPoint.Application

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer        
    i = 1
    For j = 1 To ppt.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes.Count

        If ppt.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes(j).Type = 14 And _
            Presentations(2).Slides(i).Shapes(j).Type = 14 Then _            
                Debug.Print _
                    ppt.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                    Presentations(2).Slides(i).Shapes(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    Next j
End Sub
```

General Notes:

- This obviously doesn't account for changed formats or placings.
- I would expect some trouble as soon as there are new Shapes added to one of the Slides.
- Afaik, when adding a new shape it should have `Shape(Index) = Shapes.Count+1`, but you never know what people do to your
  presentation...

Hopefully, someone comes up with a more elegant approach to solving this!